# I think I might have some sort of malware on my Ubuntu laptop. Does anyone know what it could be?

Tags: ssh, malware

When I run rkhunter, it outputs this log with warnings (too long to post here): http://pastebin.com/hW6C5LGU

And when I run chkrootkit it outputs this with a warning about Operation Windigo/Ebury: http://pastebin.com/ZqTBfGyJ

It says "Searching for Linux/Ebury - Operation Windigo ssh...        Possible Linux/Ebury - Operation Windigo installed"

Is this something I should be worried about? If so, what does it do and how do I remove it, should I do a full reinstall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds normal to me. Looking at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709545/chkrootkit-says-searching-for-linux-ebury-operation-windigo-ssh-possible-l), it appears the cause of the error message you're seeing is the lack of an illegal operation string in the output of `ssh -G`. However, the same is true on my system, which I'm 99.9% sure is currently clean.

As to the warning output in rkhunter, have a look at [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/229942/warning-flagged-by-the-rkhunter) - that also sounds normal.

However, if you do conclude that your machine is infected, the safest way to remove any malware is to wipe and reinstall the system.