# Operation Windigo present after fresh install

Tags: system-installation, malware, chkrootkit

I had been noticing strange behavior and logs on my ubuntu machine.

I recently installed Ubuntu from a USB.  I set the installation to write over blank space, and used LVM/LUKS encryption.  I setup the UFW to default deny all incoming and allow all outgoing.  I also allowed incoming 443/tcp and 80/tcp.

The first thing I did was install chkrootkit.

It reported that I had a possible infection of Linux/Ebury Windigo.  I looked it up and read its history here -> http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/operation-windigo.html

Can anyone explain how an installation from a checksummed ubuntu 16.04 ISO can result in instant rootkit infection?  Do I have a hidden partition on my drive?  Has my bios been compromised?  I did notice the system time was changed in the OS AND BIOS which led to this reinstallation.

Comment: There were apparently some false positives for this problem - you might check the procedures in [https://askubuntu.com/questions/709545/chkrootkit-says-searching-for-linux-ebury-operation-windigo-ssh-possible-l](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709545/chkrootkit-says-searching-for-linux-ebury-operation-windigo-ssh-possible-l)

Comment: Yeah, it's probably the BIOS. Replace the motherboard.